# MS-Access optimization

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a small dilema about the work assignment that i got. I am a part time student assistant at this institution where my boss wants me to "fix" the MS-Access database we have. The problem is that i don't know where to start. I mean my boss is not so computer savvy and wouldn't be able to tell what exactly is wrong with it. All i know is that it's extremely buggy, inefficient(no cross-sectional automatic update. I mean when i do the new entry and save it in the database, and go to "reports" to print it, i have to erase old info with an employee name and a number and input new info). Anyways, to make the long story short, I was hoping to get some tips on how to assess the entire database structure i.e. figure out the efficiency level and to figure out what is it that i need to fix in order to make it better. I am sorry for being vague but i do accept vague answers :). So if you direct towards certain book, website, or some other source where i can learn what questions i need to ask about the database in order to be able to optimize it, i will be happy.

P.S. My MS-Access efficiency level is effectively 0.
I do have some programming experience in JAVA, R, MATLAB and excel of course.

Comment: Wow!!! close votes within 5 minutes. Hold on guys! Lets try to help him.

Comment: @GKED what language? There is no documented way of optimizing access database. We will need more info to help you. Amy be its not the DB that needs change. It can be the code as well.

Comment: @Shoban, help him with what? I can hardly see any programming related question the way we expect to see them here. Example: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I don't believe a book or tutorial can help you, databases are another world with other rules and techniques than you mainly need in Java (programming) and calculation and mathematics (R, Matlab, Excel). You cannot understand the structure of a database by reading a book. Access help is okay to understand basic concepts, then open the various objects, by order as they are listed in the database window, in design view, i.e., 1. tables, 2. queries, 3. forms, 4. reports.

Comment: @mupan, you can in fact read books to help learn what the database structure could be and there are books on Access specifically. That will help the poster asses his problem in terms of how far awy from the correct design his current one is and then he can start to ask questions about how to fix what he foudn out was wrong, but without any theorectical basis for waht he should have, he has nowhere to start to ask specific questions.

Comment: You have to open the property field for each child object to understand e.g. what is responsible for the not updated fields, is it an unbound field, i.e., a report field not directly connected to a table field but having its value set in the report_load event code -> VBA?

Comment: @HLGEM: I understand what you suggest, just had no benefit from reading primers personally, but I would suggest O'Reilly then: [link](http://www.amazon.com/Access-Database-Design-Programming-3rd/dp/0596002734/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1297368447&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allen Browne has a [website with excellent tips](http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html) for beginners through experts.  It's as good a starting place as any, but it doesn't change the fact that good database design is more than just a ten-minute tutorial away.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to laugh, but way back many, many years ago when I was first learning about  using Access, I found the book Access for Dummies very helpful.  See if they have a version for the version of Access you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You have some good "starting point" answers on Access specifically in the other answers. Keep in mind that Access is more than a database--it's a database application development system (I do **not** want to get into any arguments about how *good* it is for its intended purpose, and the OP probably doesn't want to read them).

For non-specific database basics, which are the foundation on which the rest of the Access sytem depends, I recommend [**this tutorial**](http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_db_schema/index.htm). If your database schema design is solid, you can build from there. If your schema is messed up, you'll never be able to salvage anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a list of books](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dd547097).  Access Cookbook, 2nd Edition by Ken Getz, Paul Litwin, Andy Baron has a good reputation.